# how to set "minimum" margins within @page css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

Based on the examples I found, one way to set margins in print-settings is to use @page (or specify it directly in @media print) within scss. @page-rule for margin delivers positive effect as expected, as long as I set "Default" as the value for margins inside Print-Settings in Chrome.

[chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpi5z.png)

Are there any ways also, how to give specific margins for "Minimum"- and "User identified"-values for print-browser with @page css?

Comment: I've used also min() on margin, but has zero effect like below:

@page {
    size: auto;
    margin-top: min(100mm);
    margin-right: min(100mm);
    margin-bottom: min(100mm);
    margin-left: min(100mm);
}

Comment: i've figured out, that within @media print { . . . } margin-behaviours (for instance) can be specified to minimum like (margin-right: min(5px), so

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean to use `@media-query`

[Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: No, I wasn't intended to use `@media-query`. It is indeed @media rules, but only for print-cases. [check the definition under print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)